# common-lisp の setq はいつ使うのか？

Tags: common-lisp

LISPの入門書を読んでいると、まず`setq`で変数の束縛を行っているケースを良く見ますが、`sbcl`などの実装系では`setq`を使うと、Unused variableの警告が出ます。

以前の質問でも、`defparameter`や`let`, `let*`を使用して変数の束縛を行った回答が付き、`setq`が使われていることはありませんでした。

では、`setq`はどんなケースで使われるのか教えて下さい。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> setqはどんなケースで使われるのか教えて下さい。

setqは、変数への代入全般で使います。基本的に他の言語と変わりありません。
Lisp特有のところとしては、シンボルというオブジェクトが値を格納する場所を持っており、この場所に値を代入できることです。

コンピュータ言語には、

1. 変数宣言がいらない言語
2. 変数宣言が必要な言語

がありますが、Common Lispは、変数宣言が必要な言語です。(let、defvar、etcでの宣言)
では、変数宣言なしでの`setq`は不正なのかというと、その場合、

```lisp
(setq x 42)
```

は、

```lisp
(set 'x 42)
;; もしくは、
(setf (symbol-value 'x) 42)
```

として扱われるので不正ではありません。
上記のコードは、シンボルというオブジェクトが保持する値を格納する場所に値を代入しています。

コンパイラが警告を出すのは、変数宣言がされていない`x`変数を含む、`(setq x 42)`という表現が、意図的なものか、ミスによるものかの区別がつかないためです。
(なお、SBCLは対話的動作でも式をコンパイルします)

プログラミングスタイル的には、変数宣言なしでの代入は、他の言語と同じく不正だと考えて問題ないでしょう。

> LISPの入門書を読んでいると、まずsetqで変数の束縛を行っているケースを良く見ます

大体の理由を挙げると

- LISPの入門書が古い(Common Lisp以前など)
- 入門段階では、変数宣言についての説明を端折っている。

あたりでしょう。厳密さより分かり易さを優先しているのかと思います。